# How to draw a double \hline in a table without interrupting vertical lines

Tags: tables, rules

I need to draw a double line after the first row in a table, but when using `\hline` twice, this interrupts the vertical lines:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline 
1 & 2 & 3 \\ \hline \hline
4 & 5 & 6 \\ \hline
7 & 8 & 9 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

produces:

[image]

This is without using any additional packages. How can I change this is such a ways that the vertical lines are not interrupted?

Comment: hhline from package of that name

Comment: I tried this: `1 & 2 & 3 \\ \hhline{}` but then the horizontal line just disappears. I also tried `1 & 2 & 3 \\ \hhline{===}` but then the vertical lines were still interrupted. If not that, what is the proper argument for this function?

Comment: The right one is `1 & 2 & 3 \\ \hhline{|=|=|=|}`

Answer (score 65, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hhline}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline 
1 & 2 & 3 \\ \hhline{|=|=|=|}
4 & 5 & 6 \\ \hline
7 & 8 & 9 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In case you have a table with a double vertical line, see here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/152101/23992

Comment: I think there's a spelling error, `hhline` is not defined. Also, I can't seem to get this to work when the layout is `|c c|c c|`.

Comment: @DmitriNesteruk if `hhline` is not defined then you have not copied the code correctly to include the `hhline` package.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ahh, missed that, thanks. incidentally, in my case, the argument ended up being `|==|==|`... but this makes no sense! :) *sigh*

Comment: @DmitriNesteruk why does it make no sense? `|==|==|` is what I would expect if your columns are specified as `|cc|cc|`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I kind of assumed that the space between the `c` tags had some meaning. I guess not. Thanks for the explanation, btw, have some +1s.

Comment: What would be corresponding solution for \cline{}?

Comment: @user22180 `|==|~~|` ?

Answer (score 3):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`, the vertical rules cross the double horizontal rules (of `\hline\hline`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline 
1 & 2 & 3 \\ \hline \hline
4 & 5 & 6 \\ \hline
7 & 8 & 9 \\ \hline
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

In fact, with `{NiceTabular}`, you have a key `hvlines` to draw all the horizontal and vertical rules and you still have the ability to put a `\Hline\Hline` where you want (`\Hline` is provided by `nicematrix` and draws the rule with PGF/TikZ instead of using the standard `\hline`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{ccc}[hvlines]
1 & 2 & 3 \\ \Hline\Hline
4 & 5 & 6 \\ 
7 & 8 & 9 \\ 
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

The output is the same.