# How to draw two \hline and two vertical line?

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, rules, tabu

I want to draw a table with two `\hline` and two vertical line. But as shown in the figure, the first vertical line do not cross the two hline. How to solve this problem?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hhline}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c||c||c}
\hline 
1 & 2 & 3 \\ \hhline{=|=|=}
4 & 5 & 6 \\ \hline
7 & 8 & 9 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Minimize the use of vertical lines in tables. They disturb more than they help.

Comment: +Svend I couldn't disagree more. SOME tables look nice without vertical lines, but there are MANY tables that demand them, and the notion that they should be avoided at all cost is a horrific one that is way too prevalent  in the LaTeX community.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As stated in the [`hhline` package documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/tools/hhline.pdf), `|` gives you a  vertical line which *cuts* through a double (or single) hline, whereas `#` gives a double hline segment between two vlines.

So, to correct your situation (leaving aside the aesthetic issues) simply use, `#` in place of the `|` in the argument for `\hhline`.

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hhline}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c||c||c}
\hline 
1 & 2 & 3 \\ \hhline{=#=#=}
4 & 5 & 6 \\ \hline
7 & 8 & 9 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

---

You get the following output.

[image]

---

For further reading, please see the 
[`hhline` package documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/tools/hhline.pdf) mentioned above. Also, you may like to see [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140409/hhline-double-line-imperfection) as well.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use vertical lines in tables; they disturb more than they help.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\toprule
1 & 2 & 3 \\
\midrule
4 & 5 & 6 \\
\midrule
7 & 8 & 9 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: It is not the answer to OP's question.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke I don't agree with you. We've hand a "don't do this" answers with alternative provided before. Since TeX is about typography, it's not wrong to provide typographical alternatives to what OP asks for. See e.g. [What's the quickest way to write “2nd” “3rd” etc in LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/4120)

Comment: Thanks so much! It is beautiful but MMA gives the answer 'to' the question.

Answer (score 0):

For information, in `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`, the vertical rules (specified by the symbols `|` in the preamble) are not interrupted by the double horizontal rules (specified by `\hline\hline`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{c||c||c}
\hline 
1 & 2 & 3 \\ \hline\hline
4 & 5 & 6 \\ \hline
7 & 8 & 9 \\ \hline
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score -3):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c| |c| |c}
\toprule
1 & 2 & 3 \\ \hline
\hline
4 & 5 & 6 \\ \hline \hline
7 & 8 & 9 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

It looks pretty!
[image: This looks nicer]

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.